# Garbage collection vs manual memory management

Tags: java, c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, jvm

This is a very basic question. I will formulate it using C++ and Java, but it's really language-independent.
Consider a well-known problem in C++:

```
struct Obj
{
    boost::shared_ptr<Obj> m_field;
};

{
    boost::shared_ptr<Obj> obj1(new Obj);
    boost::shared_ptr<Obj> obj2(new Obj);
    obj1->m_field = obj2;
    obj2->m_field = obj1;
}
```

This is a memory leak, and everybody knows it :). The solution is also well-known: one should use weak pointers to break the "refcount interlocking". It is also known that this problem cannot be resolved automatically in principle. It's solely programmer's responsibility to resolve it.

But there's a positive thing: a programmer has full control on refcount values. I can pause my program in debugger and examine refcount for obj1, obj2 and understand that there's a problem. I also can set a breakpoint in destructor of an object and observe a destruction moment (or find out that object has not been destroyed).

My question is about Java, C#, ActionScript and other "Garbage Collection" languages. I might be missing something, but in my opinion they

1. Do not let me examine refcount of objects
2. Do not let me know when object is destroyed (okay, when object is exposed to GC)

I often hear that these languages just do not allow a programmer to leak a memory and that's why they are great. As far as I understand, they just hide memory management problems and make it hard to solve them.

Finally, the questions themselves:

Java:

```
public class Obj
{
    public Obj m_field;
}

{
     Obj obj1 = new Obj();
     Obj obj2 = new Obj();
     obj1.m_field = obj2;
     obj2.m_field = obj1;
}
```

1. Is it memory leak?
2. If yes: how do I detect and fix it?
3. If no: why?

Comment: It's not a memory leak. It doesn't **protect** you from leaking memory, but there's nothing to prevent you from releasing those objects in the destructor. Memory management is part of **application** design; low-level hacks won't make up for lack of design.

Comment: do not allow a programmer to leak a memory is not the case, but these langauges could protect you from leaking memory in most of the cases.This is a big advantage for those programmers who don't have any idea about memory, we atleast don't need to worry too much about memory leak when assign them some small projects

Comment: There's no access to refcounts because most implementations don't maintain refcounts, and languages in general are careful not to impose restrict more implementation details than absolutely necessary (as this prevents better implementations -- faster, more robust, more useful, etc.).

Comment: obligatory jargon file:  http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/koans.html#id3141202

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Managed memory systems are built on the assumption that you don't want to be tracing memory leak issue in the first place.  Instead of making them easier to solve you try to make sure they never happen in the first place.

Java does have a lose term for "Memory Leak" which means any growth in memory which could impact your application, but there is never a point that the managed memory cannot clean up all the memory.

JVM don't use reference counting for a number of reasons

- it cannot handled circular references as you have observed.
- it has significant memory and threading overhead to maintain accurately.
- there are much better, simpler ways of handling such situations for managed memory.

While the JLS doesn't ban the use of reference counts, it is not used in any JVM AFAIK.

Instead Java keeps track of a number of root contexts (e.g. each thread stack) and can trace which objects need to be keeps and which can be discarded based on whether those objects are strongly reachable.  It also provides the facility for weak references (which are retained as long as the objects are not cleaned up) and soft references (which are not generally cleaned up but can be at the garbage collectors discretion)

Comment: Rust may be worth mentioning as a middle ground.

Answer (score 6):

AFAIK, Java GC works by starting from a set of well-defined initial references and computing a transitive closure of objects which can be reached from these references. Anything not reachable is "leaked" and can be GC-ed.

Comment: Maybe they are well-defined for Java, but not for me :). Where can I learn more about these references?

Comment: @Nick I don't work in Java, so I unfortunately don't know. Try Java documentation or uncle Google.

Comment: The basic reference for garbage collection in general is [_The Garbage Collection Handbook_](http://gchandbook.org/) by Richard Jones, Antony Hosking, and Eliot Moss. It has extensive discussions of most, if not all, of the various memory management strategies (including the reference counting used by shared_ptr).

Answer (score 2):

Java has a unique memory management strategy. Everything (except a few specific things) are allocated on the heap, and isn't freed until the GC gets to work.

For example:

```
public class Obj {
    public Object example;
    public Obj m_field;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int lastPrime = 2;
    while (true) {
        Obj obj1 = new Obj();
        Obj obj2 = new Obj();
        obj1.example = new Object();
        obj1.m_field = obj2;
        obj2.m_field = obj1;
        int prime = lastPrime++;
        while (!isPrime(prime)) {
            prime++;
        }
        lastPrime = prime;
        System.out.println("Found a prime: " + prime);
    }
}
```

C handles this situation by requiring you to manually free the memory of both 'obj', and C++ counts references to 'obj' and automatically destroys them when they go out of scope.
Java does *not* free this memory, at least not at first.

The Java runtime waits a while until it feels like there is too much memory being used. After that the Garbage collector kicks in.

Let's say the java garbage collector decides to clean up after the 10,000th iteration of the outer loop. By this time, 10,000 objects have been created (which would have already been freed in C/C++).

Although there are 10,000 iterations of the outer loop, only the newly created obj1 and obj2 could possibly be referenced by the code.

These are the GC 'roots', which java uses to find all objects which could possibly be referenced. The garbage collector then recursively iterates down the object tree, marking 'example' as active in addiction to the garbage collector roots.

All those other objects are then destroyed by the garbage collector.
This does come with a performance penalty, but this process has been heavily optimized, and isn't significant for most applications.

Unlike in C++, you don't have to worry about reference cycles *at all*, since only objects reachable from the GC roots will live.

With java applications you *do* have to worry about memory (Think lists holding onto the objects from all iterations), but it isn't as significant as other languages.

As for debugging: Java's idea of debugging high memory values are using a special 'memory-analyzer' to find out what objects are still on the heap, *not* worrying about what is referencing what.

Comment: Java's memory management strategy is hardly unique. Garbage collection dates back to Lisp. Also, different JVMs can implement garbage collection differently.

Comment: @JayElston Lisp invented Garbage collection? And I know its a simplification, JVMs have a lot of leeway on howto collect crud :)

Comment: If you believe [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) :-)

Answer (score 1):

The critical difference is that in Java etc **you are not involved in the disposal problem at all**. This may feel like a pretty scary position to be but it is surprisingly empowering. All the decisions you used to have to make as to who is responsible for disposing a created object are gone.

It does actually make sense. The system knows much more about what is reachable and what is not than you. It can also make much more flexible and intelligent decisions about when to tear down structures etc.

Essentially - in this environment you can juggle objects in a much more complex way without worrying about dropping one. The only thing you now need to worry about is if you accidentally glue one to the ceiling.

As an ex C programmer having moved to Java I feel your pain.

Re - your final question - it is not a memory leak. When GC kicks in **everything** is discarded except what is reachable. In this case, assuming you have released `obj1` and `obj2` neither is reachable so they will both be discarded.

Comment: "System knows much more about what is reachable and what is not than you". Hmmm... It sounds good until I have no memory troubles. But what should I do when my program is out of memory? I do know how to investigate and optimize memory manegement in "C++ like" environment. But what should I do in Java?

Comment: @Nick In Java you should either a) increase the amount of memory or b) optimise your program to use less memory.  You can use a memory profiler in either case to determine what the best solution is.  Java comes with a free one VisualVM which you can attach to any running process and while it is not great, it is good place to start.  Optimising memory usage is Java is either a) simpler as many of the issues in C++ just don't happen or b) much harder because you don't have as many way to squeeze every last byte of your system.  Given you buy 32 GB for $300, I go with option a)

Answer (score 1):

**Garbage collection is not simple ref counting**.

The circular reference example which you demonstrate will not occur in a garbage collected managed language because the garbage collector will want to trace allocation references all the way back to something on the stack.  **If there isn't a stack reference somewhere it's garbage**.  Ref counting systems like `shared_ptr` are not that smart and it's possible (like you demonstrate) to have two objects somewhere in the heap which keep each other from being deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Garbage collected languages don't let you inspect refcounter because they have no-one. Garbage collection is an entirely different thing from refcounted memory management. The real difference is in determinism.

```
{
std::fstream file( "example.txt" );
// do something with file
}
// ... later on
{
std::fstream file( "example.txt" );
// do something else with file
}
```

in C++ you have the guarantee that example.txt has been closed after the first block is closed, or if an exception is thrown. Caomparing it with Java

```
{
try 
  {
  FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream( "example.txt" );
  // do something with file
  }
finally
  {
  if( file != null )
    file.close();
  }
}
// ..later on
{
try 
  {
  FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream( "example.txt" );
  // do something with file
  }
finally
  {
  if( file != null )
    file.close();
  }
}
```

As you see, you have traded memory management for all other resources management. That is the real diffence, refcounted objects still keep deterministic destruction. In garbage collection languages you must manually release resources, and check for exception. One may argue that explicit memory management can be tedious and error prone, but in modern C++ you it is mitigated by smart pointers and standard containers. You still have some responsibilities (circular references, for example), but think at how many catch/finally block you can avoid using deterministic destruction and how much typing a Java/C#/etc. programmer must do instead (as they have to manually close/release resources other than memory). And I know that there's using syntax in C# (and something similar in the newest Java) but it covers only the block scope lifetime and not the more general problem of shared ownership.